# Change the condition to test for based on the argument passed to the function

Tags: javascript

I "inherited" a JS function from a previous programmer working here. I noticed there are in his code two functions that do the same thing and they differ just a little.

The first function takes no arguments and inside its body he tests a condition this way:

```
function parseAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (obj.flag == 0) {
            // do many other things I omit
        }
    }
}
```

The second function:

```
function parseOne(stringOne) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (obj.flag == 0 && obj.str = stringOne) {
            // do other things I omit (same identical things as in the function parseAll
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to convert the functions to one function, passing `null` when is the case covered by the first one, and passing a `string` when it should be called the second.

So, the difference between the two would only be the condition to test.

How to programmatically change the condition to test for, based on the argument passed to the function? I want to test `obj.flag==0` if I pass `null` and `obj.flag==0 && obj.str=stringOne` if I pass a `string`. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily detect whether an argument was passed in, in a couple of ways. If `stringOne` will never be `""` when you actually want to use it for the "one" case, then:

```
function parseOne(stringOne) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (obj.flag == 0 && (!stringOne || obj.str === stringOne)) {
            // do other things I omit (same identical things as in the function parseAll
        }
    }
}
```

(I changed your `obj.str = stringOne` to `obj.str === stringOne`. With just one `=`, it's an assignment, and I'm assuming that was a typo.)

Then you can call `parseOne` with no arguments at all (don't even need to pass in `null`) for the "all" case.

Note that the above assumes that it's never meaningful for `stringOne` to be `""`, because `""` is falsey, so `!stringOne` is true and we'd treat it like the "all" case. If it's meaningful to pass in `""` and only want to handle that one string, you have to change things a bit:

```
function parseOne(stringOne) {
    var one = typeof stringOne !== "undefined";
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (obj.flag == 0 && (!one || obj.str === stringOne)) {
            // do other things I omit (same identical things as in the function parseAll
        }
    }
}
```

There's a third option, which is to check `arguments.length` which is the number of arguments actually passed to the function (all functions have an `arguments` object in scope during the call), but on some JavaScript engines that can dramatically slow down the call (though not usually in a way that really matters), and it's not really needed here.